# An exercise of Lan wen's book

Tags: vector-spaces, banach-spaces, jordan-normal-form

Let $A: E \to E$ be a linear isomorphism and $E$ a finite dimension Banach space. Prove that $A$ is hyperbolic if and only if $A$ has no eigenvalue of absolute norm $1$.

This is an exercise of Lan wen's book, Differentiable Dynamical Systems. I did 
"$A$ hyperbolic so $A$ has no eigenvalue of absolute norm $1$."

For the reciprocal I had an idea, but I don't know how to finish.

Suppose $A$ has no eigenvalue of absolute norm $1$. 
By the Jordan canonical form Theorem exist a basis $B$ of $E$ such that $A$ can be written in Jordan blocks.

Let $E^1$ be the space generated by the vectors of $B$ that are associated with the eigenvalues with norm $<1$ and $E^2$ the space generated by the vectors of $B$ that are associated with the eigenvalues with norm $> 1$.

It is clear that $E=E^1\oplus E^2$. But I am having a hard time to show that $E^1= E^s$ and $E^2=E^u$.

where 
$E^s = \{ x \in E \;|\; A^n(x) \to 0, n\to \infty\}$ and $E^u =\{ x \in E \;|\; A^{-n}(x) \to 0, n\to \infty\}$

Thank you very much.

Comment: So $E$ is a complex Banach space? Please include definitions of $E^s$ and $E^u$. What have you tried?

Comment: Hi @TedShifrin the books says $E$ is a finite-dimensional normed vector space.

Comment: About what I try. I don't know how to work with the jordan Basis. If The basis where formed by eigenvectors the exercise would be trivial, but the basis are not formed by eigenvectors, so I don't know what to do.

Comment: So for simplicity assume the eigenvalues are real (although you may have to complexify if the eigenvalues are complex). If $|\lambda|<1$ can you show that any Jordan $\lambda$ block corresponds to a stable subspace? Maybe the norm of the matrix would be a useful tool. Here's a hint: You can choose a basis so that the Jordan form has $\epsilon$'s rather than $1$'s.

Comment: @TedShifrin this is the problema. I don’t know how to show that any Jordan $\lambda$ Block with $|\lambda|<1$ corresponds to a stable subspace.

Comment: Did you read what I typed in my last comment?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the hint